# Cant get over WCF's Max Received Messages error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, download

Well, I've looking for an answer to my problem for several hours but I just cant get rid of. I'm using a WCF Web service to download a file from a server. To test, I've used 3 different documents (PDF) 1 of them with a size of 24Kb and the other 2 with 60KB. I can download the first (24KB) but none of the others can be downloaded, everytime I try , Visual Studio shows this exception:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded

I've read that the default size of the buffer is 64KB, so I dont know why I can't download files with 60KB size. I've tried to change the buffer size in my config (server and client) and even try with streaming transfer and its the same thing.

Here is my .config file code (on server):

```
<system.serviceModel>

<services>      
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" name="CAVTransactions">
    <endpoint address="CAV" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bindingIntegrator"
      name="CAV" contract="ICAVContract" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://XX.XXX.X.XX:XXXX/App_Code/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="bindingIntegrator"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" >

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
           maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
           maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>

    <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600"/>
    </behavior>

  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

My .config file code (on client):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="bindingIntegrator"
           maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
           maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" >

            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                 maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                 maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/IntegratorWCFService/CAVTransactions.svc/CAV"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bindingIntegrator" contract="CAVService.ICAVContract"
            name="CAV" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My Contract:

```
[OperationContract]
Stream DownloadFileOther(string documentName);

public Stream DownloadFileOther(string documentName)
{

    System.IO.Stream str;
    try
    {
        //string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\CAV_Documents", request.FileName);
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\CAV_Documents", documentName + ".pdf");
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

        //Chequeo de existencia
        if (!fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Archivo no encontrado", documentName);
        }

        //Apertura de stream
        FileStream stram = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        str = stram;

        //resultado
        //result.FileName = request.FileName;
        //result.Length = fileInfo.Length;
        //result.FileByteStream = stram;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    return str;
    //return 0;
}
```

And the code for download the file:

```
try
                {
                    Stream stream;

                    string codigo = selectedRevision.Code.ToString();

                    stream = ClientManager.CreateCAVServiceClient().DownloadFileOther(codigo);

                    string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();


                    using (var file = File.Create("Temp\\" + key + ".pdf"))
                    {
                        stream.CopyTo(file);
                    }

                    string GuidePath = @"./Temp/" + key + ".pdf";
                    string fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(GuidePath);
                    Uri GuideURI = new Uri(fullPath, UriKind.Absolute);

                    selectedRevision.DocumentPath = GuideURI;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
```

I'd appreciate if some of you guys could give me some comments to help me. Thanks!

Comment: The error message seems to be complaining about the size of the HTTP Request, not the size of the Response. If the backing transport is HTTP, maybe try watching with Fiddler?

Comment: `ClientManager.CreateCAVServiceClient().DownloadFileOther(codigo)` - Is this referring to a custom class that creates the specified client, or is it `ClientManager` is your service reference and `CreateCAVServiceClient` is the supplied constructor?  I'm thinking if `ClientManager` is some sort of custom implementation you may be having an issue with default bindings/endpoints.  Can you show the code for `ClientManager.CreateCAVServiceClient`?

Comment: ClientManager is a class I created, and CreateCAVServiceClient is a static method that creates a CAVServiceClient. I'm going to edit the post and show the code. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your client configuration file? Even if you modified the service configuration file, client configuration always generate with the default settings. 
Please see my following blog post which has detailed how to tackle this error.

\http://thetechnocrate.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/the-maximum-message-size-quota-for-incoming-messages-65536-has-been-exceeded/

Comment: OP posted his client config and it looks to be set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

in your server config change this

```
<serviceBehaviors>

<behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
</behavior>
```

Answer (score 0):

After all, it was something Tim commented in my question. I was using a custom class to create my binding (the ClientManager.CreateCAVServiceClient) I wasn't changing the binding in that class so the buffer size hadn't being modified.Thanks to Tim for solve my problem, and everyone else for giving me advices :D!